# Which order does getTrace return calls?

Tags: php, exception, stack-trace

Probably a trivial question, but in which order does [`Exception::getTrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php) return calls? Most recent first or last? I'd like to know before I implement my error handler.

**BenTheDesigner**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you test it yourself?

```
function NestedFunc() {
    throw new Exception("test");
}

function FunctionAbc() {
    NestedFunc();
}

try {
    FunctionAbc();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getTrace());
}
```

Comment: Crozin, I would have if I was at my PC. Question posted while brainstorming on the train. Thanks